# AWS S3 uploading Images does not work when deployed to EBS but works in localhost SpringBoot (JAVA)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am able to upload images to S3 from local but not when deployed to EBS. This code works while I run it locally but the image upload does not work at all when I deploy the same code in AWS EBS. I don't see any error logs. Tried to search solution with all dead-ends. I will really appericiate it if any one can point me to right direction. I am using t2.micro instance

application.properties

```
amazonProperties.endpointUrl: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
amazonProperties.bucketName: "BUCKETNAME"
```

ProductController.java

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {
   @Autowired  
   private AmazonClient amazonClient;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    @RequestMapping(value="/addmaincategory", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String
     addmaincategory(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,BindingResult result,Model model){
        MultipartFile image= product.getProductImage();
        String imageName = amazonClient.addImage(image);    
        product.setProductImageName(imageName );
        productRepository.save(category);
        model.addAttribute("product",product);
        return "productdetails";
    }

}
```

AmazonClient.java

```
   @Service
    public class AmazonClient {
        @Autowired
        private AmazonS3 s3client;

        @Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
        private String endpointUrl;
        @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
        private String bucketName;


    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
            File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            return convFile;
        }

     private void uploadFileTos3bucket(MultipartFile file) {
           File file = convertMultiPartToFile(file);
           String fileName = "myfile.png";      
            s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();     
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            s3client.putObject(request);
        }

    }
```

IAM ROLE with trusted entity

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Attached Policy permission

[image: Attached Policy permission]

Comment: Are you sure you've properly set the permissions to allow EBS to write to the bucket?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I updated my question with the permission if it is right. Thank you

Comment: `the image upload does not work at all` In what way? Are there any errors? If not, do you log anything? How far does the execution proceeds correctly, etc?

Comment: I would advice you to create and assign a role for EBS instance with permission to write to S3 bucket instead of using access keys. The way you are connecting is strongly not recommended security wise.

Comment: @user2529284 I agree with you not to use access keys to communicate with S3 bucket and updated my code and created role for EBS and assigned permission with FULLS3ACCESS . Please refer to the updated code in my question. But it didn't solve my issue. Can you please see if I am doing anything wrong. Thank you for showing me the direction. I would appreciate if you can recommend me some working examples or documents.

Comment: Thank you all. The above code solved my issue. Please feel free to use this as reference. I did a silly mistake with my EBS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticbeanstalk Trusted Entity

```
 {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }
```

EC2 Trusted Entity

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Attached Permission in Both Case

[image: Attached Permission in Both Case]